# Help on proving an integral equation.

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the Hilbert space $L^2[0,1]$ and the linear operator $K$ defined in the 
following way:
\begin{equation*}
(Kf)(t):=\int_0^t (t-s)f(s) ds,\quad 0\leq t\leq 1,\ f\colon [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C} \mbox{ continuous.}
\end{equation*}
show that for any continuous function $f\colon [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ we have
\begin{equation*}
(K^nf)(t)=\int_0^t \frac{(t-s)^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!} f(s) ds,\quad 0\leq t\leq 1.
\end{equation*}

I tried to prove this for $n=2$, but I could not find much:
$$(K^2f)(t)=\int_0^t (t-s)\int_0^s(s-r)f(r) drds$$
I just wrote the definition and tried some integration by parts, but I confused the boundaries of the integral and I could not decide how to choose to differentiate and etc. Can you help me to calculate and prove the equation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the order of integration and get $(K^2f)(t)=\int_0^tf(r)dr\int_r^t (t-s)(s-r)ds$.  Now let $x=s-r$ so that the $s$ integral becomes $\int_0^{t-r} (t-x-r)xdx=\frac{(t-r)^3}{6}$, so $(K^2f)(t)=\int_0^tf(r)\frac{(t-r)^3}{3!}dr$.

Repeat by induction gives the desired result.

$(K^{n+1}f)(t)=\int_0^t(K^nf)(s)ds$, where $(K^nf)(s)=\int_0^s \frac{(s-r)^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}f(r)dr$.
Switch orders of integration and let $x=s-r$ we get $(K^{n+1}f)(t)=\int_0^t \frac {f(r)}{(2n-1)!}dr\int_0^{t-r}(t-x-r)x^{2n-1}dx$   The $x$ integral is $\frac {(t-r)^{2n+1}}{2n(2n+1)}$  giving $(K^{n+1}f)(t)=\int_0^t \frac{(t-r)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}f(r)dr$